# When is it safe to extend the lifetime of references into Arenas?

Tags: rust, lifetime, unsafe

I have a struct which uses [`Arena`](https://docs.rs/typed-arena/1.4.1/typed_arena/struct.Arena.html):

```
struct Foo<'f> {
    a: Arena<u64>, // from the typed-arena crate
    v: Vec<&'f u64>,
}
```

Is it safe to extend the lifetime of a reference into the arena so long as it is bound by the lifetime of the main struct?

```
impl<'f> Foo<'f> {
    pub fn bar(&mut self, n: u64) -> Option<&'f u64> {
        if n == 0 {
            None
        } else {
            let n_ref = unsafe { std::mem::transmute(self.a.alloc(n)) };
            Some(n_ref)
        }
    }
}
```

For more context, see this [Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/btj5ik/hey_rustaceans_got_an_easy_question_ask_here/eptkhan?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x).

Comment: Depends on many factors, e.g. does `Arena` drop its values when it goes out of scope? If yes, then it is not valid to do.

Comment: If you look at the typed-arena crate, it does drop the data. If you can't store the references, then how do you use the arena for non-trivial code? Do people not face this problem with arenas in practice?

Comment: They don't use unsafe and the borrow checker is preventing them from doing bad things ;) (Also it's not my task to look at the crate (which you haven't linked!), but yours as the one who asks the question).

Comment: "They don't use unsafe and the borrow checker is preventing them from doing bad things" -- that is not very helpful. The question is: "how do I solve this problem?". Answering "don't do X" without presenting alternatives doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: True that. Have you thought about making it `static`, e.g. with the `lazy_static` crate?

Comment: @hellow no I cannot have static lifetimes, I need to deallocate the arena at some point later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it safe to extend the lifetime of a reference into the arena so long as it is bound by the lifetime of the main struct?

The `Arena` will be dropped along with `Foo` so, in principle, this *would* be safe, but it would also be unnecessary because the `Arena` *already* lives long enough.

However, this is not what your code is actually doing! The lifetime `'f` could be longer that the lifetime of the struct — it can be as long as the shortest-lived reference inside `v`. For example:

```
fn main() {
    let n = 1u64;
    let v = vec![&n];
    let bar;
    {
        let mut foo = Foo { a: Arena::new(), v };
        bar = foo.bar(2);
        // foo is dropped here, along with the Arena
    }
    // bar is still useable here because 'f is the full scope of `n`
    println!("bar = {:?}", bar); // Some(8021790808186446178) - oops!
}
```

Trying to pretend that the lifetime is longer than it really is has created an opportunity for Undefined Behaviour in safe code.

---

A possible fix is to own the `Arena` outside of the `struct` and rely on the borrow checker to make sure that it is not dropped while it is still in use:

```
struct Foo<'f> {
    a: &'f Arena<u64>,
    v: Vec<&'f u64>,
}

impl<'f> Foo<'f> {
    pub bar(&mut self, n: u64) -> Option<&'f u64> {
        if n == 0 {
            None
        } else {
            Some(self.a.alloc(n))
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let arena = Arena::new();
    let n = 1u64;
    let v = vec![&n];
    let bar;
    {
        let mut foo = Foo { a: &arena, v };
        bar = foo.bar(2);
    }
    println!("bar = {:?}", bar); // Some(2)
}
```

Just like your unsafe version, the lifetimes express that the reference to the `Arena` must be valid for at least as long as the items in the `Vec`. However, this also enforces that this fact is true! Since there is no unsafe code, you can trust the borrow-checker that this will not trigger UB.

Comment: Ok, I understand what the problem is. Now, how do I solve it? How do I use the arena and store references into it? Do I refactor my data types (c.f. the reddit link where I consider some options)? Something else?

Comment: @theindigamer Perhaps you could own the arena outside of the struct and avoid unsafe code altogether. I'll add an example.

Comment: Hmm, this does solve the problem with using Arena. Thanks. However, I ran into the same problem with [string interning](https://docs.rs/string-interner/0.7.0/string_interner/struct.StringInterner.html#method.get_or_intern) which (correctly) needs `&mut StringInterner` compared to `&Arena` for the allocator. Moreover, the Arena potentially [panics at runtime](https://github.com/SimonSapin/rust-typed-arena/blob/9fd9b4ed4015790a60cf854899412c62b007c362/src/lib.rs#L167) in a multi-threaded situation behind this seemingly safe API. Oh well :-/.